# Dúvida teste de integração

Tags: c#, sql-server, testes, testes-de-unidade, visual-studio-2017

Acredito que seja uma dúvida um tanto conceitual sobre o tema, mas vamos lá:

Tenho  um método exemplo que valida um usuário conferindo se ele existe no banco de dados, dessa forma:

```
public bool ValidaCampos(string Nome)
{
    string str = "select count(*) FROM USER where racf='" + Nome "'";

    var cont = cD.ExecutaScalar(str);

    if(Cont>0)
    { return true;}

    else
    { return false;}
}
```

Embora seja um método simples, gostaria de entender qual seria a forma mais enxuta e correta de testar a operação com o banco de dados.

Comment: eu nao usaria if e else, já daria um return com o cont > 0.

Comment: Existe índice pela coluna `racf`?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

De forma muito simplificada e fazendo do jeito um pouco mais correto, mas não garantindo que esteja 100% correto pela falta de contexto da pergunta seria isto:

```
public bool ValidaCampos(string Nome) {
    cD.CommandText= "select count(*) FROM USER where racf = @user";
    cD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Nome);
    return cD.ExecutaScalar(str) > 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/VerifyUser.cs).

Note que realmente o código pode ser simplificado porque tem coisas completamente redundantes e desnecessárias, mas para ser seguro precisa adicionar outras coisas. Tem outras maneiras de fazer e de forma mais segura (este caso pode dar alguns problemas), mas teria que mudar toda a arquitetura e não só este código, e teríamos que saber mais sobre o cenário como um todo.

Alguma coisa me diz que tem outros problemas no código não exposto.

Answer (score 0):

> *(...) gostaria de entender qual seria a forma mais enxuta e correta de testar a operação com o banco de dados.*

Não é necessário contar quantas linhas atendem à cláusula `WHERE`; basta encontrar uma linha que atenda que é o suficiente para saber que o usuário já está cadastrado.

Se não houver índice pela coluna `racf`, a situação piora ainda mais com o uso de `count(*)`, pois toda a tabela será lida; imagina se são 1 milhão de linhas?!

Eis duas opções para o código T-SQL (sem considerar o restante do código):

```
string str = "SELECT case when exists (SELECT * from [USER] where racf='" + Nome + "') then 1 else 0 end;";
```

ou

```
string str = "SELECT count(*) from (SELECT top (1) * from [USER] where racf='" + Nome + "');";
```

Comment: Acredito que fazer esse tipo de concatenação em consulta no banco é bem falha, seria melhor implementar uma classe e referenciar ao um objeto por questões de segurança.

Comment: Olá Igor. A sugestão que fiz foi somente na parte do código T-SQL, considerando-se a solicitação de "_testar a operação com o banco de dados_". Ainda aguardo a resposta do autor do tópico sobre a existência de índice pela coluna `racf`, pois estou preocupado com a performance da consulta no banco de dados. E sim, é necessário ficar atento a _SQL Injection_.

Comment: sobre isso não se preocupe, estava me referindo a publicação do autor, não à sua resposta, pois acredito que voce estava respeitando as condições passadas.